# Unity Testing with PlatformIO on Native Environment - No avr-gcc libraries

Tags: unit-testing, include, avr, include-path, platformio

The guide from PlatformIO (I am using VS Code)  for unit testing seems fair enough.
However, when PlatformIO tries to build for unit tests on my local machine (environment `native`), my files won't compile. The error states that `avr/io.h` does not exist. The same files compile fine for my other environment (platform `atmelavr`, framework `arduino`).

I guess this is due to GCC being used, instead of AVR-GCC (WinAVR).

Has anybody got unit testing to work on VS Code with PlatformIO, using the native environment? 
How do I set extra include paths for a certain platform, thus supplying GCC with the missing stuff?

I tried adding the path with

```
lib_extra_dirs = "C:\Users\MYUSER\.arduinocdt\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5\avr\include"
```

with and without a trailing `\`, but it does not seem to work.

---

**(Partial) Directory Tree**

```
...\RGBPlay:.
│   platformio.ini
│
├───include
│       tTimer0.h
|
├───src
│       main.cpp
│       tTimer0.cpp
│
└───test
    └───test_tTimer
            test_tTimer_construct.cpp
```

---

**platformio.ini**

```
[env:ArduinoAsISP]
platform = atmelavr
framework = arduino
board = attiny85
upload_protocol = stk500v1
upload_flags = 
    -P$UPLOAD_PORT
    -b$UPLOAD_SPEED
upload_port = COM3
upload_speed = 19200

[env:native]
platform = native
lib_extra_dirs = "C:\Users\MYUSER\.arduinocdt\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5\avr\include"
```

The last line is an attempt of me to let the GCC compiler reach `io.h` (which is in the `...\avr\include\avr` folder).

---

**src/main.cpp**

```
1   #include <avr/io.h>
2   ...
```

---

**Error Message**

[image: Actual error message, the part discussed here is marked with green.]

Comment: What does that "native" mean by the way? Usually it means target = host which is obviously not the case for AVR.

Comment: PlatformIO's guide says it is your local machine. E.g. Windows, Linux or Mac PC.

I added GCC as the compiler for the native system, so that is the reason it does not find the files that AVR-GCC includes by default.

Comment: @Smartskaft2 and that's why it can't use anything like <avr/io.h> and avr-gcc, it doesn't exist on host system or it's not usable for it..

Comment: @KIIV so there could be stuff in those libraries that do not work properly on a system with "more of everything". I mostly want the defined constants in those headers, e.g. port addresses and port bits etc.

Comment: @Smartskaft2 It's completely different cpu/architecture. So you can test only trully multi-platform pieces of code (algorithms or so), coded without any direct dependency to the target mcu. (Or you have to fake it - but there comes possibility you just introduce more bugs into it).

Answer (score 1):

From PlatformIO documentation:

> **Desktop**
>
> PIO Unit Testing Engine builds a test program for a host machine using
>   Native development platform. This test could be run only with the
>   desktop or Continuous Integration VM instance.
>
> Note
>
> PlatformIO does not install any toolchains automatically for Native
>   and requires GCC toolchain to be installed on your host machine.
>   Please open Terminal and check that the gcc command is installed.

Conclusion: it uses hosts gcc. There will be no avr/io.h for host system as it's not running on AVR MCU.

That also means that you can test only platform independent pieces on the host system, like algorithms (separated in libraries, so it doesn't have any dependency on avr includes/libraries and can be independently included into unit tests).

Comment: All right, thank you. I guess my code is simple enough right now to not be dependent on the system, but might not be in the future. I guess I will look into testing with hardware in the loop instead.